# htaccess redirect with wildcard and not recursive

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've consolidated about 20 old pages into one new page, and want to redirect web links going to those pages to the new page.
I started out listing each one in htaccess as a Redirect 301, but thought I might save processing time to do a wildcard string match instead. Unfortunately it failed, because I suspect the page I want to go to is also caught in the wildcard.

For example I want to redirect, www.mydomain.com/catalog/listname_oranges.php, listname_lemons.php, listname_figs.php etc to redirect to www.mydomain.com/catalog/listname_addons.php

So I tried this, which failed:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/catalog/listname_.*$ /catalog/listname_addons.php

How do I fix this so its not recursive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead in your regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/catalog/listname_(?!addons\.php).*$ /catalog/listname_addons.php
```

This way, the `listname_addons.php` file won't match the regex but everything else will.